# Pass Stringbuilder message from Json [MVC-Controller]and render it in view

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, stringbuilder

I am trying to pass a `StringBuilder` message as an extra data back to ajax call but I am failing to manipulate it in client side. Below is the way I append message to `StringBuilder` and pass it back.

```
StringBuilder retMessage=new StringBuilder();
retMessage.Clear().AppendLine("Successfully added the user!"); 
//Clear will done only on Success otherwise will append the different errorMessage using AppendLine
return Json(new { result = valid, message = retMessage });
```

On the ajax Success I tried retrieving it as below but with no success.

```
 success: function (data) {
              if (data.result) {
                    ResetForm('#frmChangePwd');
                    console.log(data.message);
              },
 }
```

Below are images showing how it is passed from server side and how it is obtained in client side!!

**Server Side return**

[image: Server Side return]

**Client Side retrieval**

[image: Client Side retrieval]

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve message in client side and display it in view?

Comment: Did you try calling the to String method on the stringbuilder when you constructed the object literal.

Comment: You need to call `.ToString()` on the `StringBuilder` - `return Json(new { result = valid, message = retMessage.ToString() });`

Comment: I am trying to implement it @StephenMuecke

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke.. It works well and fine.. :)

Comment: And just by way of explanation, without `.ToString()` your passing the instance of the `StringBuilder` so the `Json` method serializes the instance from its public properties, but the actual text output is internal so its not sent - only the 3 public properties that you see in the browser

Comment: Enlightened @StephenMuecke.. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the toString method on the StringBuilder even you create the anonymous object on the return from the server.

Comment: I will try implementing this and will let you know.